# Officejs- Bind contentcontrol with customxmlpart using xml mapping

Tags: javascript, office-js, cpu-word, word-contentcontrol

I am using officeJs API with angular framework for creating Word add-in. In that I want to insert content control with custom xml part, It is possible to add customxmlpart into the document using OfficeJS API 
e.g.

Office.context.document.customXmlParts.addAsync(xml [, options], callback);

But I am not able to bind content control with custom xml part using xml mapping in officeJs API. Is it possible to do xmlmapping with content control using xml part or in any other way? I just want repeating content controls. If anyone know how to bind content control with custom xml part please provide some sample example. Your help will be appreciated.

Thanks In advance,
Pooja.

Answer (score 0):

There is no API in Office.js to do this directly. you can insert the CC with XML mappings using officeXML, but the downside is that this will not work in Word Online. CCs in Online do not support XML mappings as of the time of this writing.